# Static framework that uses a cocoapod will not compile in the main app

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I'm having problems understanding how cocoapods work with respect to a framework.  I've condensed the problem into a simple a project:

Sample project(s): https://github.com/weitzel926/WWAlertTester

This contains two iOS projects:

WWAlertTesterFramework - This is a static framework that uses a Cocoapod. The Cocoapod is an Alert Controller.  The framework provides a wrapper interface to display the cocoapod on the top-most controller.

WWAlertTesterApp - This app pulls in the framework.  It has a button.  When pressed, it uses the interface to launch the alert controller that the framework wraps.

The problem: If I don't include the pod in the Podfile for the tester app, I get compilation errors.  (Cannot load underlying module for 'AlertController' - AlertController being the name of the pod).  If I include this in my app Podfile, it works, but the console spits out errors because it is finding each method implementation in two places (locally and the framework).

How does one get this to work without having to define the pod in the app's Podfile.  The code is in the framework.  Why can't the compiler load it?  I put the framework at the root and added it to my project.  It should not be a search paths issue.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, the `WWAlertTesterFramework` in your case marks the imported module `AlertController` as being visible to `WWAlertTesterApp`. You can jump to the definition of `WWAlertTesterFramework` in Xcode, and `import AlertController` should be there.

[image]

One way to fix the error is by using [@_implementationOnly](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/docs/ReferenceGuides/UnderscoredAttributes.md#_implementationonly). In your example, just replace `import AlertController` with `@_implementationOnly import AlertController` in AlertTesterInterface.swift, and use the new `WWAlertTesterFramework` to build `WWAlertTesterApp` again. You can check again the definition of `WWAlertTesterFramework`, and `import AlertController` should be gone.

Another fix is by setting `-enable-experimental-feature AccessLevelOnImport` swift-frontend flag and change the imported module's access-level with Xcode15.2(Swift5.9).
https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0409-access-level-on-imports.md